# How can I mount a disk without formatting it?

Tags: linux

I have a disk filled with my precious data which was mounted in a machine. I want to mount this disk into another machine and read the data in it.
It seems I have to set the disk partition and format the filesystem on it.

Can I mount the disk without formatting it? Isn't the information about the partitions and filesystem in the disk inside?

Comment: "It seems I have to set the disk partition and format the filesystem on it." – could you [edit] your question to clarify what makes you think that? Is it behaviour you're seeing when you try to mount the disk, or is it something you've read? To answer your question though, the information about partitions is stored on the disk, you don't need to format it to mount it on another system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are only able to mount partitions with known filesystems on it (Yes that information is on the disk). 
For getting info about supported filesystem-types, try

```
man mount
```

If you want to give the automation a try, use (as root) :

```
mkdir /mnt
mount /dev/<your-partition> /mnt
```

and observe the output.

Probably you just forgot to specify the partition when you tried mounting ? so you should use :

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mountpoint
```

insteady of

```
mount /dev/sda /mountpoint
```

for finding out all partitions present on a disk, try

```
fdisk -l /dev/<device>
```